# How to use SetClipboardViewer Function without any window in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

According to MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052%28VS.85%29.aspx

Adds the specified window to the chain of clipboard viewers. Clipboard viewer **windows** receive a WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD message whenever the content of the clipboard changes.

But I don't want any window, I just want to hook the clipboard silently. How to code this in C# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a hidden window. If don't want to use a hidden *form*, you can create [message-only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28VS.85%29.aspx#message_only).

Comment: Thanks never heard of it before